# Select rows where column > 0 after final row where column == 0

Tags: mysql, sql

Edit 2021: I want to explain this better.

I have a table named `MyTable` with two columns; one column named `SortColumn` type `Integer` and one column named `ExpressionColumn` type `Boolean`.
I want to get all rows, sorted by `SortColumn` in ascending order, after the last row where `ExpressionColumn` was `True`.
The types are not exact.

Eg. Table with rows represented as `[SortColumn,ExpressionColumn]`, `[0:True]` will get `[0:True]`, `[0:True, 1:False]` will get `[]`, `[0:True, 1:False, 2:True, 3:True]` will get `[3:True, 4:True]`.

Leaving the old question below so as not to invalidate given answers. It had too many extra details.

---

I want to select rows after than last row where column `Number` is 0.

So with this table,

```
Id | Number
------------
0  | 5
1  | 30
2  | 10
3  | 25
```

I want to get rows with `Id` 0 to 3 inclusive.

With this table,

```
Id | Number
------------
0  | 5
1  | 30
2  | 10
3  | 25
4  | 0
```

I want to get no rows at all.

With this table,

```
Id | Number
------------
0  | 5
1  | 30
2  | 10
3  | 25
4  | 0
5  | 0  
6  | 30
```

I want to get row with `Id` 6.

SQL details: MySQL 5.6.

Comment: sqlfiddle is great, as a complement, but you should give us sample table data and expect result here too. (Remember that SO is a great archive, and the sqlfiddle link will be useless pretty soon.)

Comment: @jarlh there is sample data included in the sqlfiddle. I'm doing this right right? Do I have to do an ascii table? Right, I understand it. Will copy it right now

Comment: You should have it here too.

Comment: Please show the results you want.  The explanation is not very clear.

Comment: Specify **YOUR** MySQL server version.

Comment: mysqli 5.6. I added my explanation

Comment: The sample data is great! But also specify the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh thank you. But I don't understand, the expected result is already in there!

Comment: *after than last row where Price is 0* Does this row with `Price=0` must match `Name='Car Wash'`?

Comment: @Akina Yes, it must. I'll make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve separate records:

```
SELECT * 
FROM transaction t1
WHERE Name LIKE '%Car Wash%'
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM transaction
                   WHERE t1.id <= id
                     AND Name LIKE '%Car Wash%' -- maybe not needed? not specified
                     AND Price = 0 );
```

Retrieve their amount only:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM transaction t1
WHERE Name LIKE '%Car Wash%'
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM transaction
                   WHERE t1.id <= id
                     AND Name LIKE '%Car Wash%'
                     AND Price = 0 );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e9997c578eace8b11caad266b2cdc82b)

Answer (score 0):

you can select

```
    select 
    from my_table 
    where name like '%car%' and price > 0
```

and for count

```
    select count(*)
    from (
       select 
       from my_table 
       where name like '%car%' and price > 0
    ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

I interpret this question as "how many rows are there for "car wash" after the first row with price > 0".  If so:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*,
             min(case when price = 0 then id end) over () as id_at_0
      from transaction t 
     ) t
where name = 'Car Wash' and id > id_at_0
```

Comment: *MySQL version is 5.6.*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable myTable1
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL FROM MyTable
                   WHERE myTable1.SortColumn <= SortColumn
                     AND ExpressionColumn = True );
```